# Dynamic logical expression parsing/evaluation in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing

I have a need to evaluate user-defined logical expressions of arbitrary complexity on some PHP pages.  Assuming that form fields are the primary variables, it would need to:

- substitute"varibles" for form
  fields values;
- handle comparison operators,
  minimally ==, <, <=, >= and > by
  symbol, name (eg eq, lt, le, ge, gt
  respectively);
- handle boolean operators not, and, or and
  possibly xor by name, symbol (eg !,
  &&, || and ^^ respectively);
- handle literal values for strings
  and numbers;
- be plaintext not XML (eg "firstname
  == '' or lastname == ''); and
- be reasonably performant.

Now in years gone by I've written recursive descent parsers that could build an expression tree and do this kind of thing but thats not a task I'm relishing in PHP so I'm hoping there are things out there that will at least get me some of the way there.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask, did you manage to create a function for simple expression parsing without using eval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [create_function](http://www.php.net/create_function), it creates an anonymous function from the string parameters passed, I'm not sure about its performance, but it's very flexible...

Comment: Ooooo nice.  I'm no PHP expert so I wasn't aware of create_function.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Good to note here that is deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0

Comment: Please offer a more educational answer than a mere link to the manual.

Answer (score 12):

Much time has gone by since this question was asked, and I happened to be looking for an expression parser for php.  I chose to use the [ExpressionLanguage](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) component from Symfony 2.4.  It can be installed with no dependencies from composer via [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/expression-language).

`composer require symfony/expression-language`

Comment: I evaluated nearly all ExpressionParsers mentioned here on stackoverflow and google. I ended up using this one.

Comment: Link-only answers make fragile answers and are better welcomed as comments.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want the users to write out functions in non-PHP, and then have PHP interpret it?

If so, you could simply take their string and replace "lt" with "<" and "gt" with ">" ... then do eval().

I have a hunch the problem isn't this simple, but if it is, eval() could do the job.  Of course, then you're opening yourself up for any kind of attack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The answer may in fact be that simple.  I'm no PHP expert.  Java is more my schtick.  None of these expressions are coming from the outside world.  Its all internal config.

Comment: problem with `eval` is that  it executes arbitrary PHP code that is passed to it.  Traditionally there has been an issue with injection attacks.  i.e. users can pass in code that will be plugged in and executed in the same environment as production code.  Depending on the cleverness or maliciousness of the user, that code can cause havoc and undesired side effects.  You would have to be very careful and clever in your checker/replacer to be able to filter out all potential issues within arbitrary PHP

Answer (score -1):

You can try adapting my Evaluator class (https://github.com/djfm/Evaluator), it does arithmetic expressions (for now) and you can use variables too. All the major PHP operators are implemented.

Comment: 1 == 1 && 2 == 2 Returns 0.  I would have expected it to return 1.
The Parsed Expression is: ( ( 1 == ( 1 && 2 ) ) == 2 )
That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Link-only answers make fragile answers and are better welcomed as comments.