# Evaluate an expression in php without Eval in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, expression, eval

I've stored an expression in a database, e.g.:

```
$expression = (({TENOR} <= 90) AND ({DEPOSIT_AMOUNT} > 0) AND {PENALTY_BASIS} = 0 )
```

I want to evaluate the expression in an IF...Else statement and get the results

```
if ($expression) {action} else {other action}
```

What is the best way to achieve the result? I've tried

```
$this->parser->parse_string($string, $data, TRUE);
```

but the output is always a string, hence if...else statement outputs TRUE every time.

Comment: What is the reason why you can't use eval here?

Comment: As per PHP... Caution

The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: My question would be why do have that string expression saved that needs to be parsed and evaluated? Presumably there is some code that generates the expression. That code _should_ have some inputs, as a guess, I'd say they are `90`, `0` and `0` but whatever - if you just save the _inputs_ you can replay them against the expression generation function and you should get the same expression back. In which case you do not need to open yourself to `eval` problems, nor do you need to find a way to re-parse everything. Your problem literally becomes "I need to store a couple of plain values in DB".

Comment: @vlaz The structure of Database is fixed and i have changing values and hence cant design a special table for storing values. For above example, all i need to have is substitute the values of TENOR, DEPOSIT_AMOUNT, PENALTY_BASIS (Which can be done through $resukt = $this->parser->parse_string($string, $data, TRUE)), put it in if else condition and execute the results...

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution at previously answered post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15054960/1611242)

The library can be found out at [here](https://github.com/djfm/Evaluator)

Thanks all for the help...